# How to access "Saved Audiences" with the Facebook Ad API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to access "Saved Audiences" that were [created with the Power Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFglw.png) via the Ad API.

I've tried

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/?fields=customaudiences"
```

but that returns nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @RedBottle Paste this: `act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>?fields=saved_audiences{name,targeting}`

Into the Graph API Explorer: https://i.imgur.com/j8MFG2J.png

Link to Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Answer (score 9):

[Evan Chen, Solutions Engineer at Facebook told me to use:](https://www.facebook.com/events/1745038632447104/permalink/1751174698500164/)

```
GET act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/saved_audiences
```

or

```
GET act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>?fields=saved_audiences
```

Comment: "Unsupported get request"